# MPI_send and MPI_receive string

Tags: c++, mpi

I've read a bunch of pages, but i can't find a solution for my problem: I have to pass an array of 3 integers from the root process to worker processes where:

- first int is the number of pages to be verified by each process
- the second int is the id where to start to verify
- the third int is the length of the string to be searched in that pages.

After sending this array, I send the string to be searched. The    problem is on receive: the length of the sent string is correct, but    when i output the string i have this: for example if i send "sport",    on output i have "sport222|||". Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     int rank;
     int noOfProcs;
     string stringToBeSearched = "";
     int root_process;
     int ierr;
     int avgPerProcess;
     int totalNoOfPages;
     int noOfPagesForLastProc;
     int proc;
     char* receivedString = "";
     int receivedSLen;
     int dataToSend[3];
     int receivedData[3];
     vector<HtmlPage> pages;
     char* s = "";
     clock_t tStart;
     MPI_Status status;

     ierr = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
     root_process = 0;
     ierr = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
     ierr = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &noOfProcs);

     if (rank == root_process) {
        cout << "Enter text: ";
        getline(cin, stringToBeSearched);
        //calculate the number of pages to be verified by each process
        totalNoOfPages = getTotalNumberOfPages();
        avgPerProcess = totalNoOfPages / noOfProcs;
        //send the array to each process
        noOfPagesForLastProc = avgPerProcess + (totalNoOfPages % noOfProcs);
        for (proc = 1; proc < noOfProcs; proc++) {
            dataToSend[0] = avgPerProcess;
            dataToSend[1] = proc * avgPerProcess;   
            dataToSend[2] = stringToBeSearched.size();
            if (proc == noOfProcs - 1){
                dataToSend[0] = noOfPagesForLastProc;
            }
            ierr = MPI_Send(&dataToSend[0], 3, MPI_INT,
               proc, send_data_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);            
            //send the string to be searched
            ierr = MPI_Send(stringToBeSearched.c_str(), stringToBeSearched.size(), MPI_CHAR, proc, send_data_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        //verify pages in the segment assigned
        //to the root process
        //get the pages assigned

        pages = getPagesForProcess(avgPerProcess, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
            string searched = pages[i].getContent();
            const char* ch = searched.c_str();
            if (strstr(ch, s) != NULL){
               cout << "Process 0" << " founded matches at: " << endl;
               cout << pages[i].getUrl() << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        //worker process receive the array segment,
        //storing it in a "local" array
        ierr = MPI_Recv(&receivedData[0], 3, MPI_INT,
        root_process, send_data_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        receivedSLen = receivedData[2];     
        receivedString = new char[receivedSLen];
        ierr = MPI_Recv(receivedString, receivedSLen, MPI_CHAR, root_process, send_data_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        //this line of code outputs the "bad" string
        cout << "received string = " << receivedString << endl;

        //get the assigned pages to verify
        pages = getPagesForProcess(receivedData[0], receivedData[1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
            string searched = pages[i].getContent();
            const char* ch = searched.c_str();
            if (strstr(ch, receivedString) != NULL){
                cout << "Process " << rank << " founded matches at: " << endl;
                cout << pages[i].getUrl() << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "No matches founded by process " << rank << endl;
            }
       }    
    }
    cout << "Time taken for execution " << (double)(clock() - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " s." << endl;
    ierr = MPI_Finalize();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line in the code outputs the string that is "bad"?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this line of code outputs the "bad" string
            `cout << "received string = " << receivedString << endl;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your string lacks a null-terminator.

```
 receivedString = new char[receivedSLen];
```

Should be:

```
 receivedString = new char[receivedSLen + 1]();
```

This allocates 1 more character for the terminating null, and also initializes the data to the default (which is 0 anyway).

Better yet, get rid of the memory leak by using `std::vector`

```
 std::vector<char> receivedString(receivedSLen + 1,0);
 cout << "received string = " << &receivedString[0] << endl;
```

The issue you should consider is if the string can contain embedded `NULL` characters.  If so, then you have to use a different approach to how you process the string, since the function(s) you're using now rely on the terminating `\0`.

In this case where the data may have embedded `NULL`s,

```
cout << "received string = ";
cout.write(receivedString, receivedSLen);
cout << endl;
```

If using `std::vector`:

```
cout << "received string = ";
cout.write(&receivedString[0], receivedSLen);
cout << endl;
```